# How to strip specific characters that are in one of the parameters?

Tags: python, list, function, split

I have a function change_sentence that takes in two parameters "sentence" and "remove".
I want the sentence to be split every time on of the characters in "remove" is come across. And then I want each word to be moved into a list. So for example

```
change_sentence('Hello- I am! Very happy?', '-!?')
```

will return

```
['Hello', 'I am', 'Very Happy']
```

I tried using the split function but I am unsure how. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

```
from re import split
txt = 'Hello- I am! Very happy?'
breaks = '[-!?]' # square brackets makes it a proper regexp that we need
splitted = split(breaks, txt)
# ['Hello', ' I am', ' Very happy', '']
filtered = filter(bool, splitted)
# ['Hello', ' I am', ' Very happy']
cleaned = [element.strip() for element in filtered]
# ['Hello', 'I am', 'Very happy']
```

Comment: Thank you but is there any way to do this using just for/while loops/if statements? I am not this advanced yet and I am not sure how from works.

Comment: @BobStar using from is just importing a function from a module in this from re (regular expression module that comes with every python) import split.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read your question properly before I think so here I a better solution which is a (function) that uses for/if:

```
def change_sentence(sent, remove):
    T=tuple()
    L=[]
    for i in list(sent):
        if i not in remove:
            T+=tuple(i)
        else:
            L.append(''.join(T))
            T=tuple()
    return L
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a recursive function

```
def change_sentence(a,b):
    if len(b) == 0:
        return a
    else:
        return change_sentence(sum([i.split(b[0]) for i in a],[]),b[1:])
```

The function splits the sentence by each character in `b`. In order for this to work, your sentence should be a list.

```
sentence = ["Hello- I am! Very happy?",]
remove = "-!?"
```

Then

```
>>> change_sentence(sentence,remove)
['Hello', ' I am', ' Very happy', '']
```

You can use list comprehension to remove the empty string

```
>>> [i for i in change_sentence(sentence,remove) if i]
['Hello', ' I am', ' Very happy']
```

And to remove any trailing spaces from the list use `strip`

```
>>> [i.strip() for i in change_sentence(sentence,remove) if i]
['Hello', 'I am', 'Very happy']
```